Clerk 404 when signing out from a protected page (Next.js)
I have the following middleware:
import { clerkMiddleware, createRouteMatcher } from '@clerk/nextjs/server';

const publicRoutes = [
  '/',
  '/browse',
  '/sign-in(.*)',
  '/sign-up(.*)',
];

const isPublicRoute = createRouteMatcher(publicRoutes);

export default clerkMiddleware(
  (auth, request) => {
    if (!isPublicRoute(request)) {
      auth().protect();
    }
  },
  { debug: true }
);

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Skip Next.js internals and all static files, unless found in search params
    '/((?!_next|[^?]*\\.(?:html?|css|js(?!on)|jpe?g|webp|png|gif|svg|ttf|woff2?|ico|csv|docx?|xlsx?|zip|webmanifest)).*)',
    // Always run for API routes
    '/(api|trpc)(.*)',
  ],
};


Now, let's say that I have a protected route /dashboard. My issue is that if I am signed in, and if I am on the /dashboard page, and I click Sign Out via Clerk's built in <UserButton />, for a fraction of a second I see a 404 (and there's a POST request to /dashboard as well) before I am redirected to /.
Any suggestions? I understand why I'm getting the 404 but I fail to fix the issue.

I would recommend asking on the Clerk Discord server. The project maintainers are active there so they might be able to help

As it turns out there are multiple discussions about this on the Clerk Discord. Sadly, the documentation has this information rather obfuscated, but the solution - in my case - was to extend my middleware.ts with the following:
export default clerkMiddleware(
  (auth, request) => {
  if (!auth().userId && !isPublicRoute(request)) {
    return auth().redirectToSignIn();
  }
  // rest of the middleware
}

This seemed to have done the job...

The POST request is a part of the invalidateCacheAction for server actions as observed in the chain of calls leading to the request.
See the Request call stack in Dev tools 1
When a signout action is performed, clerk triggers invalidateCacheAction to delete cookies for the user.
Consequently, the fetchServerAction in the server-action-reducer
module performs the POST request in order to retrieved validation tags and determine whether to re-render the page.
The isPageRequest function called when handling unauthenticated requests on protected routes matches requests with Accept header value set to text/html.
However, the request made after the server action requests with Accept header value set to text/x-component.
You can make a custom distribution of the server package and build a custom bundle that modifies isPageRequest function. You could contribute this change upstream as well to Clerk.
const isPageRequest = (req: Request): boolean => {
  return (
    req.headers.get(constants.Headers.SecFetchDest) === 'document' ||
    req.headers.get(constants.Headers.SecFetchDest) === 'iframe' ||
    ['text/html', 'text/x-component'].includes(req.headers.get(constants.Headers.Accept)) ||
    isAppRouterInternalNavigation(req) ||
    isPagesRouterInternalNavigation(req)
  );
};


I do get a 404 for invalidate cache for Next.js. Is this then a bug in how Clerk handles this or is this the Next.js side?

This could be a bug in clerk.  You may need to verify why they do not identify requests with Accept header value of 'text/x-component' as page requests.

I'm not familiar with that API, but I may help you a little.
When you're on your Dashboard, and you click on the Sign out button, it better be a GET request.
If you're using Next.js, you may add a page to your API which would be called when you click on this button.
This page might look like this :
/api/sign-out :
import Cookies from "cookies";

export default async function (req, res) {
    // Delete session cookie
    const cookies = new Cookies(req, res);
    cookies.set("sess");

    // Redirect to home page
    res.redirect(302, '/');
}

And basically your Dashboard shall actually render something like that :
<a href="/api/sign-out">Sign out</a>

You haven't detailed much how you sign out, if my answer doesn't help, you might provide more details.

I indicated that I use Clerk’s ‘’ component. It handles the sign out automatically.

Could you please detail how you used it ? Showing the piece of code ?

I setup a sample repo which also shows the issue: https://github.com/tpiros/clerk-sample.git
